# ExecutionPolicy Bypass not working

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

```
$Adminusername = 'domain\blah'
$password = 'blah'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Adminusername, $securePassword
$path = "\\blah\script.ps1"

Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-file $path", "-command &{Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass}", "-username $username", "-roamingprofilepath $RoamingProfilePath", "-localappdatapath $localappdatapath" -credential $Credential
```

The above script is a PowerShell process that starts a 2nd PowerShell, but running it as a different user. The arguments from the first PowerShell session are passed into the second one.

It works fine, except that in the 2nd PowerShell process, execution policy doesn't bypass and it will keep prompting you to allow the script to run. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try to add "-executionpolicy bypass" to the argumentlist ?

Comment: Yes, still getting prompt. Have you got it working?

Comment: Tip: The thing with SecureStrings is __NOT__ having to save your password in clear text. Tip2: You might want to use [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6)

Comment: I think besides adding `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` you should remove the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` script block

Comment: I know about SecureStrings and it isn't really that much of an string encryption. This script is stored in Sysvol on a domain controller, so any authenticated user could grab the script and reverse the securestring. I'm using a service account anyway, so it doesn't matter. And get-credential won't help me here. This is a logon script that is applied for every user.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy` needs a `-Force` if you don't want it to nag you. (You may also want to use `-Scope Process` to ensure you don't trample over global settings.)

Answer (score 1):

this had worked for me

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "/noexit", "-executionpolicy bypass","-file \\server\share\test.ps1"
```

Comment: Excellent, this has worked for me. Looks like I needed the "/noexit" instead of "-noexit" for it to work.

Comment: @shadowz1337 please accept the answer if it solved your problem